# I am trying to get data from excel starting row 2 column b

Tags: c#, excel

I have some code that works, but it is getting the data from row 1 column a. I need it to start in row 2 column b. some times row 1 has some empty cells. when it does, the code does not go ahead and read the rest of the data in the excel file. if I put anything in the cell it will work. I don't want to have to alter the excel file each time to load it. Row 2 starting at column b will always have data.

here is a sample of the code that gets it from row 1 column a.

```
//Look for headers in top row
    var nCols=0;
    var Val = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols+1).Value;
    while (Val!=null)
    {
        nCols=nCols+1; //defualt was +1
        Val = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols+1).Value;
        var column = pfcCreate ("pfcColumnCreateOption").Create (pfcCreate ("pfcColumnJustification").COL_JUSTIFY_LEFT,Math.round(oSheet.Cells(1,nCols).ColumnWidth+1));
        columnInfo.Append (column);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to tag with the language you are using for your code.

Answer (score 0):

`Cells()` takes two parameters. The first is the row and the second is the column. So just push these values to be one greater and you should be good:

```
//Look for headers in top row
    var nCols=1;
    var Val = oSheet.Cells(2,nCols+1).Value;
    while (Val!=null)
    {
        nCols=nCols+1; //defualt was +1
        Val = oSheet.Cells(2,nCols+1).Value;
        var column = pfcCreate ("pfcColumnCreateOption").Create (pfcCreate ("pfcColumnJustification").COL_JUSTIFY_LEFT,Math.round(oSheet.Cells(2,nCols).ColumnWidth+1));
        columnInfo.Append (column);
    }
```

Comment: I did try that, but it still isn't reading it all. it stops at the first blank column. I guess I should have paid more attention to my excel file column b is also not always filled. looks like column f is the first one that is always filled, and that us in any row.

Comment: Also if I change the top var nCols=0; to anything else it throws up errors